# Issues with malloc in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I seem to be having some issues with malloc in my code. Here's what's going on.
I've got a struct created with a few values in it. From there, I'd like to make an array of structs. I think I've got the struct right, and some of the pointers, but I'm not sure.

Here's the struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[25];
    int courseID;
} course;
```

From there, I try to initiate the new struct and malloc it at the same time by this:

```
course *courses = malloc(25*sizeof(course));
```

From here, I'm getting the error:

> Invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'course*' [-fpermissive]   course
>   *courses = malloc(25*sizeof(course));

I don't really know what this means... I know I may be completely off course with this whole idea, so any help y'all can give would be great!

Comment: You're compiling as C++, not C. Change your compiler to `gcc`, or change the corresponding option in your IDE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

You must be using a C++ compiler. You want to compile with a C compiler.

Make sure your file name ends in `.c` not `.cpp` or `.cc`.

You also said you try to initialize (you said initiate but I am translating) the new struct. Malloc will not do that. Malloc allocated memory will contain random values left over from the last user of that memory. The `calloc` function might work better for what you want since it sets the memory to zero after allocating it.

Comment: I suspect "*initiate*" was ment to be "*instantiate*" not "*initialise*".

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing memory with malloc, which returns a void pointer to the allocated memory. You are then assigning this pointer to a course pointer. So there is a pointer mismatch and hence the warning. To bypass it use

```
course *courses = (course *)malloc(25 * sizeof(course))
```